# Get HU values along a trajectory volume

Tags: c++, vtk, itk

So, what I am trying to do is to calculate the density profile (HU) along a trajectory (represented by target x,y,z and tangent to it) in a CT. At the moment, I am able to get the profile along a line passing through the target and at a certain distance from the target (entrance). What I would like to do is to get the density profile for a volume (cylinder in this case) of width 1mm or so. 
I guess I have to do interpolation of some sort along voxels since depending on the spacing between successive coordinates, several coordinates can point to the same index. For example, this is what I am talking about.

[image: Trajectories]

Additionally, I would like to get the density profile for different shapes of the tip of the trajectory, for example:

[image: Different shapes]

My idea is that I make a 3 by 3 matrix, representing the shapes of the tip, and convolve this with the voxel values to get HU values corresponding to the tip. How can I do this using ITK/VTK?

Kindly let me know if you need some more information. (I hope the images are clear enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the density drill tip will encounter, it is probably easiest to create a mask of the tip's cutting surface in a resolution higher than your image. Define a transform matrix M which puts your drill into the wanted position in the CT image.

Then iterate through all the non-zero voxels in the mask, [transform](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ImageBase.html#ab003313ba1a078d89a832dc0a35d2efa) indices to physical points, [apply](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MatrixOffsetTransformBase.html#a556da80594679cea2e5f25c78c1e75fb) transform M to them, sample ([evaluate](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LinearInterpolateImageFunction.html#afcb3601185f27213e30e99e205169857)) the value in the CT image at that point using an interpolator, multiply it by the mask's opacity (in case of non-binary mask) and add the value to the running sum.

At the end your running sum will represent the total encountered density. This density sum will be dependent on the resolution of your mask of the tip's cutting surface. I don't know how you will relate it to some physical quantity (like resisting force in Newtons).

Comment: exactly what I was thinking to do as I mentioned, but why should I make a mask of resolution higher than my image? Additionally, in your previous answer you mentioned that I don't need to resample the image rather use an interpolator. If I make a mask of resolution higher than the image, I shouldn't need an interpolator right?

Comment: If you make the mask of the drill tip have coarser resolution than your image, the mask will skip some voxels entirely. If you make drill-tip mask resolution much higher than image resolution, you will just be wasting compute power. I suppose that optimal is twice higher (Nyquist–Shannon  theorem) or slightly more than that (2.1x).

Resampling uses an interpolator. If you first resample, and then use resampled image for the calculations, you are in effect resampling twice.

Comment: I tried to help, but I can't do your own work for you. My company offers consulting and collaboration, though.

Comment: I will post the code I have written. Can you help with some doubts? I am not asking you to do my work, its just that I want to validate what I am getting, the trajectory lies in an oblique slice and I probably have to implement an MPR to validate. Let me know if it is possible

Comment: You should post that code to ITK mailing list, more people watch it than ITK tag on StackOverflow. https://itk.org/ITK/help/mailing.html

Answer (score 0):

To get a profile along some path, you would use [resample filter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ResampleImageFilter.html). Set up a transform matrix which transforms your starting point to 0,0,0 and your end point to x,0,0. Set the size of the target image to x,1,1 and spacing the same as in source image.

I don't understand your second question. To get HU value at the tip, you would sample that point using a [high quality interpolator](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1WindowedSincInterpolateImageFunction.html) ([example using linear interpolator](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/LinearInterpolateImageFunction)). I don't get why would the shape of the tip matter.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The shape of the tip is in reference to the density of bone/tissue a drill will encounter. As you can imagine, a conical tip with different angles (as shown in the image) will encounter slightly different density, as compared to the others.

Comment: Additionally, can you provide an example code/link on how to use the filter for my purposes? The idea you mention is what I was thinking too, however the documentation is too general.

Comment: In your original post you didn't mention the drill. If you want to calculate the density drill tip will encounter, you don't need to resample the CT into a smaller image first. That would only simplify the modelling at the expense of double resampling.